# Apparent Contradiction to Liouville's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

The function of a real variable defined by $f(x)=\sin(x)$ is analytic everywhere and bounded because $|\sin(x)|\leqslant 1$ for all $x$ but it is certainly not a constant. Should this contradict Liouville's theorem? Why is it not a contradiction?

Comment: It is not bounded as a complex variable function.  Let $x=-1000i$.

Comment: No purely real, non-constant function is analytic in the complex plane.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The inequality $|\sin(x)|\leq 1$ is only true for real values of $x$. In fact, $\sin$ is unbounded when considered as a complex function. Note that we have 
$$
\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}
$$
so $\sin$ grows unbounded along the imaginary axis.

Answer (score 1):

The function $\sin$ [**isn't** bounded in $\Bbb C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564382/complex-sine-not-bounded).